# i have errors in the flutter build apk command

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, kotlin

[image]

when generating the apk through flutter I get the following warnings, the app works fine in the emulator but on the device when installing the apk, the cell phone says that an error has occurred

I hope to be able to emulate the apk correctly on the physical device.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line:

1. Enter cd [project]
2. Run flutter build apk --split-per-abi
   (The flutter build command defaults to --release.)
   This command results in three APK files:

- [project]/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
- [project]/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
- [project]/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk

Removing the --split-per-abi flag results in a fat APK that contains your code compiled for all the target ABIs. Such APKs are larger in size than their split counterparts, causing the user to download native binaries that are not applicable to their device’s architecture.